# Calculated value based on seekbar not displayed in textview

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

I have two seekbars and based on their value I'm doing some math and putting the result in a textview. When I'm changing the seekbar's progress, the textview is "blinking", which is normal, I suppose, as the value is removed and a new is inserted. Installing the code on an emulator, in some cases the calculated value disappears after releasing the seekbar. After putting the code on a device, the value isn't even displayed anymore. What can the problem be?
Here is some code:

```
weight = weightSeekBar.getProgress();
height = ((double) heightSeekBar.getProgress()) /100;
double bMI = weight/(height*height);
bMIValueText.setText("BMI value: " + bMI);
Log.d(TAG,"weight= " + weight + " height= " + height + " BMI = " + bMI);
```

Note: the "BMI value" text is displayed after each change. This code was implemented in the Seekbar listener's

```
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
```

method.

Comment: Is the TextView wide enough to correctly display values with long decimal representation? Try formatting the value of `bMI` to display a fixed number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: print bMI  value in Logs

Comment: @MMMM Can you post the value which you are using for seekbar I guess the problem is with your values.

Comment: @SpaceBison Can you please post this as an answer? The problem was the width of the textview. I would like to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @MMMM Done, thanks for the consideration. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextView might be not wide enough for values with longer decimal representations, causing the text to disappear. You can limit the number of digits after the decimal point so that it always fits (using `String.format()`, for example).

Answer (score -1):

Difficult to understand with the amount of code given but if you want to change in some part of your ui (view) at runtime, you will need to use a Handler.

Comment: I don't think it can be an answer for the question.